# Appcompat dependency settings for changing action toolbar color

Tags: android, xml

In my dependencies I have compiled `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'`
so, do I need to use this compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'`
because in all the tutorials I have found this dependency setting, please help.

Comment: You need only one, with the higher version.

Comment: Which one out of these two as my Android Studio version is 1.3.1 ???

Comment: The higher version, you might want to update your Android Studio if that does not work. The higher the version the better for you as all patches and additional features come bundled.

Comment: My Studio Specifications are: Current Version : Android Studio 1.3                 Android Platform version : API 23: Android 5.X (MNC) revision 1